# How to determine the exact position of a pokemons CP arc in percent, level or position?

Tags: pokemon-go

How to determine the exact position of a pokemons CP arc in percent, level or position?

This is at higher levels especially in the last third verry difficult.

So has any one an idea/suggestion how to determine this accurately, without spending much/any resources?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match up with your question.

Comment: @Pyritie: sorry yeah. I failed and ahve to cahnge!

Comment: Is this calculator serious when there is Mew in the screenshot or could Mew's CP already been found out through the sources? :D

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355: It seems to be serious. As it is well known that the 6 not available Pokemon are allready existing in the database. So from the same datamining it is probably possible to pick the stats. As I said, I'm using this tool allready for quite a time, and it never estimated a range where my pokemons had been outside of the estiamted range. Just have a look and convince your self. I made the screenshot myself... admited, I choose Mew as I expected that one would increase the interest of this post :P

Comment: Marking as off topic, as this seems to be about a service outside of the game itself.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: I'm asking about how to read the progress of the bar which is visually present in the game. nothing else. I could remove all that extra informations, but I would expect peeople then would start to tell me how to maximize the bar or noting this is a duplicate of "How strong is my pokemon" or what ever. I really just want to know if there is any trick i can determine without modifying my device, to say the arc has x°. Nothing about anything else.

Comment: The screenshot you posted isn't from Pokemon Go, it's from the 3rd party tool you linked to. We don't support those kinds of tools. If you want to edit your question to include an in-game screenshot and question, that would more likely be answerable here. Voting to close this for now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding a 3rd party tool that is not part of the game.

Comment: @TimS. So the site does not encourage it to explain what you ask about as long I intend to use the information gained for a 3rd party? I mean this question on a break down is "How to determine the excact progress of the CP bar?" But as this would cause a lot of answers that wouldn't help me, I just intended to explain what I want to use the info for. But if this is not allwoed, I'll simply edit everything out that trys to explain what I ask about. let me know if my edit will satisfy you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an Android app called [PokeGo Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fancydevs.pokegomaster) which comes with an Arc overlay. Using it, you can simply enter your current Trainer level and move the arrow around until the black circle on it perfectly covers the white circle of the actual arc. As long as the Pokemon view screen is scrolled all the way up and Trainer level is entered correctly, the overlay matches the real level perfectly using the datamined calculation for the arc's position.

The app conveniently also offers IV calculation, which is probably your intent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Silph Road Community's mined data. Still looking for the exact post.

Anyways, the formula's they used have been implemented in  [IV this calculator](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4tkk75/updated_iv_calculator_automatically_calculate_ivs/) and in [this Silph Road website's Pokemon Rater](https://thesilphroad.com/research), which might be related or close enough on what you are looking for.